# How can I add an sqlite database to Apache Superset?

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-superset

[image: error]

I'm trying to add a python sqlite3 generated database to superset. Getting that strange error. Is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 5):

You have to modify superset configuration (config.py file) adding this parameter:

> PREVENT_UNSAFE_DB_CONNECTION = False

This is the link to a similar question in superset github repository: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/9748, it points to the request to add this security measure.